# After Moving Laravel directory to parent, can't see files on Laradock workspace

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, docker, laradock

After installing laradock on a laravel folder
and setup the workspace
I have moved all the directory to parent directory

directory from >

```
parent/laravelproject/{project files}
parent/laravelproject/laradock/{laradock files}
```

changed to >

```
parent/ {project files}
parent/laradock/{laradock files}
```

when I use

```
docker-compose exec workspace bash
```

can't see laravel project files anymore

tried to reverse the operation with

```
mv . machine-x-php-server-app/
```

I got this error

> mv: cannot move '.' to 'the emptyprojectfolder/.': Device or resource busy

should I remove every thing and start from the beginning or there is a configuration file that I could edit and fix every thing again

Answer (score 0):

Solved by

```
sudo mv ~/parent/!(laravelproject) laravelproject/
```